# How to fix bearing cup for fixings loose wobbly wheel hub of old bicycle?

Tags: wheels, repair, hub, bearings

I have watched videos for Bicycle Freewheel Disassembly/Assembly, and disassembled my damaged bicycle. The back wheel of it started to Cranking, and by opening its part based of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_vRbBRPr3c) video instruction:

[image]

I have bought one ball bearing for it, but it seems not fit in its hole as you can see:

[image]

Also you can see below that,there is some corrupted part inside the hole which I guess there must be something inside it like which I understand it is broken and detached to two part as you can see below:

[image]

So, if possible, I want to know how can I replace bearing cup([sample photo of cup, but not my case](https://www.parktool.com/assets/img/repairhelp/hub74.jpg)!)? Maybe by removing the bearing cup of other side or something else.

Comment: Close as I can tell from the images, the bike originally had "caged" bearings, and the cage has disintegrated.  The first thing to do is to remove all the balls, clean out the race, and then replace ALL the balls ("full race minus one") with new balls, sized to match the old ones.  (Take a couple of balls to a bike shop for them to measure.)  The race appears to be "spalled" to a degree, but it's hard to tell how bad it is.

Comment: Your last picture has an insert picture of a freehub, which takes a slide-on cassette.  Your first photo is of a freewheel, where the clicking parts are in the same unit as the cogs.   Did you remove a freehub from your bike?

Comment: @Daniel R_Hicks, in the last picture you can see that the cone has been damaged and broken from its walls, so i guess i must replace entire  wheel hub!

Comment: @Criggie, yes i have removed the freehub.

Comment: @sosa - I don't see a cone in the picture.  There's a cup, but no cone.

Comment: @Daniel R_Hicks, yes i have seen [this picture](https://www.parktool.com/assets/img/repairhelp/hub74.jpg) and i have changed the cone with cup, it the title and ...(the Cone was selected before base of this [picture](https://www.parktool.com/uploads/images/blog/repair_help/freehubparts.jpg)!)